# Tensor Flow Conv1D for binary classification CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm creating a Conv1D layer in a CNN for binary classification, and I'm quite new to Machine Learning and I need some help to figure out the correct values for Conv1D:

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
    filters, kernel_size, strides=1, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last',
    dilation_rate=1, groups=1, activation=None, use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros',
    kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs
)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to determine the "Right" hyper-parameters that will fit my dataset best.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: @DavidS I would like to know what process can I follow to find the best values for my dataset

Comment: @DavidS Do you think it make sense for me to iterate over some values and see the results I will get?

Comment: @DavidS Ok thank you, I will try to automate this process, so I will start with a value that was used in another work and try to vary the values. I was thinking that it will be too brute force this routine, I was wondering if I could have same kind of bias so I would not choose some irrelevant values. But as you said, it is not as easy as this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the completion, here is the documentation of [`tf.keras.layers.Conv1D`](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/) that explain what each parameter is for.

There is no such flow! This is one of the issues in deep learning, there is no "magic" way of selecting the best hyper-parameters to fit your problem. Once you are more experienced you might be able to make an educational guess which will work fairly good.

A way to address it, is just setting multiple possible valid options for each of the hyper-parameter you wish to tune and iterate them efficently.

One way you can do it in `keras` is using the `GridSearchCV` here is a couple of good starting links:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/

https://www.kaggle.com/shujunge/gridsearchcv-with-keras

Comment: Thank you, I`ve used the GridSearchCV once for SVM, but I did not knew it could be used for other techniques as well...

Comment: @Guilherme definitely is, this is a standard way of hyper-parameter searching. I wish there were ones supplied by TF or torch that will be even better and more suited